# How can i populate multiple paths in my DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want different values from the nested schema. How can I populate them so that every field is showing me its nested data and not the object ID?
I'm using MongoDB and node/express.

**This is my postDB where the post schema is defined:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        body: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
      comments:[{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "comment"
      }],
      category:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
      creator: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "user"
      }
  },{timestamps : true}
 

)
  


module.exports = mongoose.model('postData', postSchema);
```

**This is my commentDB which is referenced from the postDB:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Using the Schema constructor, create a new CommentSchema object
// This is similar to a Sequelize model
var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // `body` is of type String
    creator: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user"
  },
    body: String
  },{timestamps : true});
 
  var Comment = mongoose.model("comment", CommentSchema);
  
  module.exports = Comment;
```

**This is how I'm trying to populate:**

```js
router.get('/READ', (req,res)=>{
  posts.find({}, function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }else{
    
      res.json({post})
      }
        }
      )
      .populate([{path:'creator'}, {path:'comments'}])
      
    })
```

However the results i get from this does not populate every object ID.

For example:

```js
{
            "comments": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f8d91d8f8550044f0f755c8",
                    "creator": "5f84e5b1d893ac42dcc9cb78",
                    "body": "This looks cool",
                    "createdAt": "2020-10-19T13:17:12.323Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-10-19T13:17:12.323Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5f8d92e82ecfbe34b8f6375b",
                    "creater": "5f84e5b1d893ac42dcc9cb78",
                    "body": "hello",
                    "createdAt": "2020-10-19T13:21:44.463Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-10-19T13:21:44.463Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                
            ],
            "_id": "5f887cef6fd7d34548a592ea",
            "title": "A DESCRIPTIVE PARAGRAPH EXAMPLE",
            "body": "\"The room in which I found myself was very large and lofty. The windows were ",
            "category": "Finance",
            "creator": {
                "joined": "2020-10-15T12:14:23.888Z",
                "posts": [
                    "5f887cef6fd7d34548a592ea",
                    "5f887e0d6fd7d34548a592ec",
                    "5f887e266fd7d34548a592ed",
                    "5f887e586fd7d34548a592ee",
                    "5f89bfccc2bebd40b07b044a",
                    "5f89c36e906bbb27b84af897",
                    "5f89c7614199d52b141ff249",
                    "5f89c7ea4199d52b141ff24a",
                    "5f8c5ab175ef762ed89eddba",
                    "5f8c5be2d7fac046f0021d9f"
                ],
                "_id": "5f88481d00ed460960da90f8",
                "username": "kenwaysharma",
                "email": "kenwaysharma@gmail.com",
                "password": "$2b$10$p3qjmdSKWIF9qAagZoqbjuG34cjOgXTe5XYER0aowwviIS65COVlu",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "__v": 0,
            "updatedAt": "2020-10-20T05:42:56.320Z"
        }
```

**Here is the userDB:**

```js
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Username is required!"],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email is required!"],
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [isEmail, "Please enter a valid email!"]
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password is required!"],
        minlength: [6, "Enter atleast 6 characters!"],
    },
    comments:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "comment"
    }],

    posts:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "postData"
    }],
  },{timestamps : true});
```

**GET users**:

```js
router.get('/USERS', (req,res)=>{
  User.find({}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }else{
          res.send(user)
          }
        }
      ).populate('comments') .populate('posts')

    })
```

How do I get the creator data inside of comments instead of just its object ID?

**Update:**
I also tried selecting the creator inside comments like
.populate('comments', 'creator')
but it still gives me the creator object ID in a string.

**Update 2:**
I have added the code for userDB to which the commentDB and postDB references.
Also added the GET users just to see how it works in postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try chaining multiple populate methods and using the exec method to pass your callback.

```
posts.find({})
.populate({
   path: 'comments',
   populate: {
       path: 'creator',
       model: 'user'
   }
})
.populate('creator')
.exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.json({post})
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work. I also tried selecting the creator inside comments like .populate('comments', 'creator')

Comment: @KenwaySharma could you please show me how you are adding data? Please check if you are setting the object ids correctly.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see and tell me what else you require.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was not able to open the link. Getting 404.